# Calling solidity smart contract with javascript to mint token does not seem to work

Tags: javascript, ethereum, web3js

I have a newby ethereum question--just getting started and trying to understand the Ethereum dev environment.

I have a very simple 721 test contract that I deployed to Ropsten and I can use REMIX to use it and it works to mint and to view balance of tokens (tokenCounter) etc.

Here is the 'contract' : https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x97E0175415cB7D758cFB0ffc27Be727360664B90

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.0;
 
import "@0xcert/ethereum-erc721/src/contracts/tokens/nf-token-metadata.sol";
import "@0xcert/ethereum-erc721/src/contracts/ownership/ownable.sol";

contract Icollect is NFTokenMetadata, Ownable {
 
 uint256 public tokenCounter;

  constructor() NFTokenMetadata () {
    nftName = "Icollect";
    nftSymbol = "ICOL";
    tokenCounter = 0;
  }
 
  function mint(string calldata _uri) external onlyOwner {
    super._mint(msg.sender, tokenCounter);
    super._setTokenUri(tokenCounter, _uri);
    tokenCounter = tokenCounter + 1;
  }
}
```

The contract seems to work for minting tokens when I test locally with this test javascript and hardhat

```
async function main() {

    const contract_address = "0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3";      
    const Icollect = await ethers.getContractFactory("Icollect");
    const icollect = await Icollect.attach(contract_address);

    const mint_return = await icollect.mint("https://test.test");    
    console.log("mint returned: ", mint_return);
    
    console.log("owner:", await icollect.owner());
    console.log("owner:", await icollect.ownerOf(0)); 
    console.log("symbol:", await icollect.symbol());
    console.log("URI:", await icollect.tokenURI(0));
    console.log("token counter:", await icollect.tokenCounter());    
  }
  
  main()
    .then(() => process.exit(0))
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
      process.exit(1);
    });
```

**The PROBLEM: When I try to mint a token from a web page I can't seem to get the 'mint' transaction to work (when I need gas). However, viewing variables works (like name and owner of contract).  Any idea what I'm doing wrong here.**

```
const transaction = contract.methods.mint(NFT_URI);
```

I'm building the object, then signing it and then sending it. The transaction seems to work but I don't see the additional token.

Here is one of the example 'mint' transaction using code below: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x6f3fc389355ffedfe135ac049837ac2d1a6eb6aad1dd10b055addfa70814e0fd
But using REMIX to query 'tokenCounter' shows that I never increase the count.

```
document.getElementById('mintbutton').onclick = async function() {
        let NFT_URI = document.getElementById("nft_uri").value;                                            
        let contract_address = document.getElementById("contract_address").value;                                            
        const contract = await new web3.eth.Contract(abi, contract_address);  
        let account_address = document.getElementById("account_address").value;  
        const account = web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(privateKey).address;        
        const transaction = contract.methods.mint(NFT_URI);
        let nonce_count = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account_address);        

        //build the transaction            
        const txObject = {
            nonce: nonce_count, 
            to: account_address,
            //value: web3.utils.toHex(21000),
            //gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(1000000),
            gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('10','gwei')),            
            gas: await transaction.estimateGas({from: account}),
            data: transaction.encodeABI()
        };

        const signed  = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(txObject, privateKey);        
        const return_from_send = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signed.rawTransaction);
                        
        return_string = 
            "blockHash: " + return_from_send.blockHash + "<br>" +
            "blockNumber: <a href='https://ropsten.etherscan.io/block/"  + return_from_send.blockNumber + "'>" + return_from_send.blockNumber + "</a><br>" +
            "contractAddress: " + return_from_send.contractAddress + "<br>" +
            "cumulativeGasUsed: " + return_from_send.cumulativeGasUsed + "<br>" +            
            "from: <a href='https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/" + return_from_send.from  + "'>" + return_from_send.from + "</a><br>" +
            "gasUsed: " + return_from_send.gasUsed + "<br>" +
            "status: " + return_from_send.status + "<br>" +
            "to:  <a href='https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/" + return_from_send.to + "'>" + return_from_send.to + "</a><br>" +
            "transactionHash: <a href='https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/" + return_from_send.transactionHash + "'>" + return_from_send.transactionHash + "</a><br>" +
            "transactionIndex: " + return_from_send.transactionIndex + "<br>" +
            "type: " + return_from_send.type + "<br>"; 

        $('#mint_return').html(return_string);            
        
        var x = document.getElementById("showDIV3");        
        x.style.display = "block";

    }
```

Here is a link to the console.log https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7hcv.jpg

Comment: `I don't see the additional token.` Where do you expect to see it? Why do you expect to see it there?

Comment: Can you add your error? What does the console output?

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa - I am expecting to see the variable tokenCounter increase if a new token is minted.  When I test for that in Remix or in some simple test.js code it is staying the same.

Comment: @PatrickCollins - I'll add a picture to the original post that has a screenshot of the test webpage.  there is no error in the console.  the transaction completes and as you can see from the link above the transaction is on the blockchain.  but somehow the transaction to mint the token was not correct because it seems the token was never minted.

Comment: I suggest you verify your contract source code on EtherScan and then you see in the symbolic output of your Ethereum transactions. Then you can see any state they change on EtherScan itself, which is very robust source of information.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa - thank you for the advice.  when I did the comparison of a REMIX EtherScan of creating a token and my JavaScript creation of a token it clearly showed that mine was to 'SELF'  and REMIX was to 'OUT'.  This lead me to the fact that my transaction object had the wrong address (I had account_address and not contract_address).  It now works.  Thank you for the recommendation.  I didn't realize how good of a debugging tool EtherScan was going to be :-)

Comment: Here is another debugging tool for public blockchain transactions https://tenderly.co/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the wrong address in the transaction object. I had the account address and not the contract address. Correction below.

```
//build the transaction            
    const txObject = {
        nonce: nonce_count, 
        to: contract_address, //NOT account_address,
        //value: web3.utils.toHex(21000),
        //gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(1000000),
        gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('10','gwei')),            
        gas: await transaction.estimateGas({from: account}),
        data: transaction.encodeABI()
    };
```